# "for" Loop for printing

Tags: c#

I am having a nightmare figuring out how to stop "0 Bottles" label to print...

Example:

```
Line one - 3 Cases 0 Bottles

Line two - 1 Cases 6 Bottles

Line three - 0 Cases 5 Bottles

Line four - 1 case 0 Bottles
```

Need to print label for each case:

```
for Line one = L1- 1 case, L2- 1 case, L3- 1 case. 

for Line two = L1- 1 case, L2- 6 Bottles.

for Line three = L1- 5 Bottles.

for Line four = L1- 1 case.
```

But I am getting an extra label printed for each line that has "0 Bottles"...

```
for Line one = L1- 1 case, L2- 1 case, L3- 1 case, L4- 0 Bottles.  

for Line two = L1- 1 case, L2- 6 Bottles.

for Line three = L1- 5 Bottles.

for Line four = L1- 1 case, L2- 0 Bottles.
```

My code

```
  foreach (DataRow dr in dtaGI.Rows)
         {
             Label = ARchivos.Clone().ToString();
           Label=  Label.Replace("[&PRODUCTDESCR]", dr["Description"].ToString())
             .Replace("[&PRODUCTCODE]", dr["ProductCode"].ToString())
             .Replace("[&PACKDESC]", dr["PAckDescr"].ToString())
             .Replace("[&ROTATION]", dr["rotationNum"].ToString())
             .Replace("[&SIZE]", dr["CaseLOL"].ToString() + "L")
             .Replace("[&BPC]", dr["CasesPerPallet"].ToString());
             TotalLabel = "              Total  " +dr["cases"].ToString() +  "c  " + dr["Bottles"] +"b";

             for(int i = 0 ;i<Convert.ToInt32( dr["cases"]);i++)
             {
                 Labels.Append(Label.Replace("[&TOTALS]", "1 Case   " + TotalLabel )).Append(Environment.NewLine );
             }

             Labels.Append(Label.Replace("[&TOTALS]", dr["Bottles"].ToString() + " Bottles" + TotalLabel)).Append(Environment.NewLine);

         }
```

Please let me know your thoughts.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Its hard to figure out what you are trying to do. But if you don't want "0 bottles" to print when there are 0 bottles, add something like this: `dr["Bottles"].ToString() == "0" ? "" : dr["Bottles"].ToString() + " bottles"`

Comment: Hi Marius, my issue is that with code above I always have an extra label "0 Bottles" printed if I only have 3 cases (for example).

Comment: @rostonline, can you post more context of the DataTable and the presentation of the Label control(s)?

Comment: Thank you for your time. Found an answer and I can't be more specific. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtaGI.Rows)
{
    Label = ARchivos.Clone().ToString();
    Label=  Label.Replace("[&PRODUCTDESCR]", dr["Description"].ToString())
     .Replace("[&PRODUCTCODE]", dr["ProductCode"].ToString())
     .Replace("[&PACKDESC]", dr["PAckDescr"].ToString())
     .Replace("[&ROTATION]", dr["rotationNum"].ToString())
     .Replace("[&SIZE]", dr["CaseLOL"].ToString() + "L")
     .Replace("[&BPC]", dr["CasesPerPallet"].ToString());
    TotalLabel = "              Total  " +dr["cases"].ToString() +  "c  " + dr["Bottles"] +"b";

    for(int i = 0 ;i<Convert.ToInt32( dr["cases"]);i++)
    {
         Labels.Append(Label.Replace("[&TOTALS]", "1 Case   " + TotalLabel )).Append(Environment.NewLine );
    }

    if (dr["Bottles"].ToString() != "0") {
         Labels.Append(Label.Replace("[&TOTALS]", dr["Bottles"].ToString() + " Bottles" + TotalLabel)).Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi icemanind, It worked!!! I was silly and was trying to applied "if" a bit higher and it didn't work... Great.